# How to split an iterable into two lists with alternating elements

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I want to split an iterable into two lists with alternating elements. Here is a working solution. But is there a simpler way to achieve the same?

```
def zigzag(seq):
    """Return two sequences with alternating elements from `seq`"""
    x, y = [], []
    p, q = x, y
    for e in seq:
        p.append(e)
        p, q = q, p
    return x, y
```

Sample output:

```
>>> zigzag('123456')
(['1', '3', '5'], ['2', '4', '6'])
```

Comment: See also: [Extract elements of list at odd positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433695)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If `seq` is a sequence, then:

```
def zigzag(seq):
  return seq[::2], seq[1::2]
```

If `seq` is a totally generic iterable, such as possibly a generator:

```
def zigzag(seq):
  results = [], []
  for i, e in enumerate(seq):
    results[i%2].append(e)
  return results
```

Comment: @Sridhar, don't think of it as lazy, think of it as *time-efficient*. I spent half an hour working working on an algorithm to do this with a *for* loop (for *x* columns, not just two). And although I got it working, it just didn't seem *pythonic* - I suspected there was an easier way. Sure enough, I didn't remember that lists have *step* variables (as shown in this Answer), which makes it trivial.

Answer (score 11):

This takes an iterator and returns two iterators:

```
import itertools
def zigzag(seq):
    t1,t2 = itertools.tee(seq)
    even = itertools.islice(t1,0,None,2)
    odd = itertools.islice(t2,1,None,2)
    return even,odd
```

If you prefer lists then you can `return list(even),list(odd)`.

Answer (score 9):

```
def zigzag(seq):
    return seq[::2], seq[1::2]
```

Comment: Only works for lists while the other solution works for any iterable.

Comment: true, but title did specify a list

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to clear something. Say you have a list

```
list1 = list(range(200))
```

you can do either :

```
## OPTION A ##
a = list1[1::2]
b = list1[0::2]
```

or

```
## OPTION B ##
a = list1[0:][::2] # even
b = list1[1:][::2] # odd
```

And get have alternative elements in variable ***a*** and ***b***.

But **OPTION A** is twice as fast