# Split a list into half by even and odd indexes?

Tags: python, list, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Python program to split a list into two lists with alternating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442782/python-program-to-split-a-list-into-two-lists-with-alternating-elements)

### Problem

Given a list like this:

```
list1 = [blah, 3, haha, 2, pointer, 1, abcd, fire]
```

I expect to get this output:

```
list = [3, 2, 1, fire]
```

So what I want is to make a list of even elements of the former list.

### What I tried

I tried using a `for` statement and tried to delete 2nd element while appending them to the list, but it didn't work out:

```
count = 0
for a in list1:
 list2.append(a)
 if count % 2 = = 1:
  list2.pop(count)

print list2
```

Comment: This question (and it's answers) are both better and more generic than the question which it is marked a duplicate of.

Comment: And this answer to a third question is the best: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153541/74291

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This should give you what you need - sampling a list at regular intervals from an offset 0 or 1:

```
>>> a = ['blah', 3,'haha', 2, 'pointer', 1, 'poop', 'fire']
>>> a[0:][::2] # even
['blah', 'haha', 'pointer', 'poop']
>>> a[1:][::2] # odd
[3, 2, 1, 'fire']
```

Note that in the examples above, the first slice operation (`a[1:]`) demonstrates the selection of all elements from desired start index, whereas the second slice operation (`a[::2]`) demonstrates how to select every other item in the list.

A more idiomatic and efficient slice operation combines the two into one, namely `a[::2]` (`0` can be omitted) and `a[1::2]`, which avoids the unnecessary list copy and should be used in production code, as others have pointed out in the comments.

Comment: thank you very much :) i didn't know this kind of thing existed! it really helped

Comment: @H.Choi: this is covered very early in every tutorial, including [the official one](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  You're going to be missing out on a lot of cool stuff if you don't read one..

Comment: Why `[0:][::2]` and `[1:][::2]` instead of `[::2]` and `[1::2]`? This will copy the list unnecessarily.

Comment: -1 with this syntax. It is unnecessary and non-ideomatic. Use the idiomatic Python slice `[::2]` for even and `[1::2]` for odd.

Comment: I think the answer below is easier to understand. Combining two concepts in one answer confused me.

Answer (score 64):

You can use list slicing. The following snippet will do.

```
list1 = ['blah', 3, 'haha', 2, 'pointer', 1, 'poop', 'fire']
listOdd = list1[1::2] # Elements from list1 starting from 1 iterating by 2
listEven = list1[::2] # Elements from list1 starting from 0 iterating by 2
print listOdd
print listEven
```

**Output**

```
[3, 2, 1, 'fire']
['blah', 'haha', 'pointer', 'poop']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just slice the list:
For odd : `a[1::2]`
For even : `a[::2]`