# Python skipping over result using for loop, json, openweathermap api

Tags: python, json, loops, iterator, openweathermap

I'm still new to Python while exploring, learning, and today I'm working with JSON and trying to skip every other result. How do I skip, pass, or "continue" every other result? I've tried using continue, iteration, islice, ranges, and next(), but I just cannot quite seem to get this specific behavior done. Here is my code:

```
import requests, pytemperature, json

r = requests.get('http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?
lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1')
dict = r.json()
select_data = dict['list']

for box in select_data:
    if 'dt_txt' in box:
        print(box['dt_txt'], box['main']['temp_min'], box['main']  
 ['temp_max'], box['wind']['speed'], box['weather'][0]['description'])  
    else:
        print('no found')
```

In above link you can find the complete JSON file, but my output looks like the following(~40 rows total):

```
2017-11-01 00:00:00 284.786 285.03 1.4 clear sky
2017-11-01 03:00:00 281.496 281.68 1.6 clear sky
2017-11-01 06:00:00 279.633 279.75 1.06 clear sky
```

Final result should look like

```
2017-11-01 00:00:00 284.786 285.03 1.4 clear sky
2017-11-01 06:00:00 279.633 279.75 1.06 clear sky
```

Side note: In the end I am trying to print the date, temp_min, temp_max, main, and description. I will be converting the temp from kelvin to fahrenheit then using gmail to text message me each day the new forecast. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `select_data` is a list, you could slice it.

```
for box in select_data[::2]:
    if 'dt_txt' in box:
        print(box['dt_txt'], box['main']['temp_min'], box['main']  
 ['temp_max'], box['wind']['speed'], box['weather'][0]['description'])  
    else:
        print('no found')
```

`[::2]` is a notation that tells python to retrieve some elements of the list, but, instead of retrieving all of them, it uses steps of two. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433695/extract-elements-of-list-at-odd-positions) is a great explanation of how this works.

One example for the sake of completeness:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> print(a[::2])
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.