# Sort on 2 columns which are inter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe :

```
start  end
1      10
26     50
6      15
1      5
11     25
```

I expect following dataframe :

```
start  end
1      10
11     25
26     50
1      5
6      15
```

here sort order is noting but end of nth row must be start+1 of n+1th row.If not found, search for other starts where start is one.

can anyone suggest what combination of sort and group by can I use to convert above dataframe in required format?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform the df to a list and then do:

```
l=[1,10,26,50,6,15,1,5,11,25]
result=[]
for x in range(int(len(l)/2)):
    result.append(sorted([l[2*x],l[2*x+1]])[1])
    result.append(sorted([l[2*x],l[2*x+1]])[0])
```

This will give you `result`:

```
[1, 10, 26, 50, 6, 15, 1, 5, 11, 25]
```

---

To transform the original df to list you can do:

```
startcollist=df['start'].values.tolist()

endcollist=df['end'].values.tolist()

l=[]
for index, each in enumerate(originaldf):
    l.append(each)
    l.append(endcollist[index])
```

---

You can then transform `result` back to a dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'start':result[1::2], 'end':result[0::2]})
```

Giving the result:

```
    end start
0   10  1
1   50  26
2   15  6
3   5   1
4   25  11
```

The expression `result[1::2]` gives every odd element of `result`, `result[0::2]` gives every even element. For explanation, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12433705/8565438

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!                                                                              
but will this ensure that start,end pairs in original dataframe remain same?

Comment: Edited the answer, is that satisfying now?

Comment: the sort order of the output is not correct.Also I tried your solution for array [26, 50, 1, 10,  6, 15, 1, 5, 11, 25],but didn't work

Comment: Changed order of lines in the first for loop of my answer, might want to try again.