# How to make a list of certain items from a different list

Tags: python, list

For example: `list1 = [1t, 1r, 2t, 2r, 3t, 3r...., nt, nr]`. How do I make a list `list_t` that has all `t` items from `list1`? I tried using the following for loop:

```
for i in list1[0:]:
    list_t =[i.t]
```

But this only assigns the first item to `list_t`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: It is not a duplicate

Comment: it contains your answer, if you just read and understand what's already answered there.

Comment: Another dupe Q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433695/extract-elements-of-list-at-odd-positions

Answer (score 0):

If your list has the same items repeated at the same time step, then:

```
list1 = ['1t', '1r', '2t', '2r', '3t', '3r']

# list[start:stop:step]
l2 = list1[0::2]
print(l2)
```

will solve your problem.

However, if what you mean is that you have a list of strings and you need to extract the strings with t on it, then you can just test if `t` is in the element, like so:

```
l2 = list()
for i in list1:
    if 't' in i :
        l2.append(i)

print(l2)
```