# Why list comprehension skip list's element?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Today get the interesting result when creating a new solution for the task by list comprehension.

```
def checkio(array: list) -> int:
 if array:
    return sum([x for x in array if array.index(x) % 2 == 0]) * array[-1]
 else: 
    return 0

assert checkio([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == 30, "(0+2+4)*5=30"
assert checkio([1, 3, 5]) == 30, "(1+5)*5=30"
assert checkio([6]) == 36, "(6)*6=36"
assert checkio([]) == 0, "An empty array = 0"
assert checkio([-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]) == 1968
```

When I decided to do debugging I have seen that the sixteenth element was skipped. Why? On the Internet, I didn't find describe this cause.

Comment: Which sixteenth element was skipped? You mean -24? Why do you think it was skipped?

Answer (score 0):

array.index(x) will return the index of the first occurrence of that value, thus if you have duplicates in the array that would not work. You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433695/extract-elements-of-list-at-odd-positions), you could achieve what you want with a list slicing:

```
arr = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]
print(arr[::2])

Out:
[-37, -19, 29, 3, -64, 36, 26, 55, 84, -65]
```

Comment: In this case - it's 84 at positions 9 and 16...