# Python - Split a List into 2 by even or odd index?

Tags: python

What is **the most Pythonic way** of splitting up a list `A` into `B` and `C` such that `B` is composed of the even-indexed elements of `A` and `C` is composed of the odd-indexed elements of `A`?

e.g. `A = [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7]`. Then `B` should be `[1, 2, 5]` and `C` should be `[3, 6, 7]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list into half by even and odd indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702414/split-a-list-into-half-by-even-and-odd-indexes)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a stride slice:

```
B, C = A[::2], A[1::2]
```

Sequence slicing not only supports specifying a start and end value, but also a stride (or step); `[::2]` selects every second value starting from 0, `[1::2]` every value starting from 1.

Demo:

```
>>> A = [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7]
>>> B, C = A[::2], A[1::2]
>>> B
[1, 2, 5]
>>> C
[3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Awesome! Fast and beautifu! Thanks!