# Funtion value store in int on python.how?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst=[1,3,4,2,555,3,324,30,80,100,200,280,43,654,223,34,6,65]

def oddeven(lst):
    even=0
    odd=0
        
    for i in lst:
        if i%2==0:
            even=even+1
                   
    for k in lst:
        if k%2!=0:
            odd=odd+1
           
    print("number of even:",even)
    print("number of odd :",odd)

    print(" even number: ",i)
    print(" odd number: ",k)
    
oddeven(lst)
```

I want the output to be:

```
print(" even number: ",i) # => print all even numbers in lst
print(" odd number: ",k)  # => print all odd numbers in lst
```

Ex:

```
>>print(" odd number: ",k)
 odd number: 1,3,6...
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list into half by even and odd elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702414/split-a-list-into-half-by-even-and-odd-elements)

Comment: How is 6 an odd number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst=[1,3,4,2,555,3,324,30,80,100,200,280,43,654,223,34,6,65]


   def oddeven(lst):

      even=0
      odd=0


    for i in lst:
        if i%2==0:
            even=even+1
        else:
            odd=odd+1

    print("number of even:",even)
    print("number of odd :",odd)

    print("Even numbers",end=":")
    for i in lst:
        if i%2==0:
            print(str(i),end=",")


    print("\nOdd numbers",end=":")
    for i in lst:
        if i%2!=0:
            print(str(i),end=",")



    oddeven(lst)
```

Instead of having two for loops, you can have one to count both even and odd numbers.
Then to print all odd and all even I used two different loops.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def oddeven(lst):
    odd = [str(x) for x in lst if x % 2 == 1]
    even = [str(x) for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]
    print("number of even:", len(even))
    print("number of odd :", len(odd))
    print(" even number  :", ', '.join(even))
    print(" odd number   :", ', '.join(odd))
```

This prints:

```
number of even: 11
number of odd : 7
 even number  : 4, 2, 324, 30, 80, 100, 200, 280, 654, 34, 6
 odd number   : 1, 3, 555, 3, 43, 223, 65
```