# Splitting a list into two seperate lists, by every other item in python

Tags: python, list

Hello I have a quick question I cant seem to solve.

I have a list:

```
a = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6]
```

And I want to split this list into two seperate ones by everything other item such that:

```
b = [item1, item3, item5]
c = [item2, item4, item6]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python program to split a list into two lists with alternating elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442782/python-program-to-split-a-list-into-two-lists-with-alternating-elements)

Answer (score 6):

Use slicing, specifying a step:

```
b,c = a[::2], a[1::2]
```

Comment: The result you want is then zip(b, c).

Comment: Sorry - I was answering another question :-). Your solution is great - upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Using filter is one option:

```
a = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6]
b = filter(lambda x: a.index(x) % 2 == 0, a)
c = filter(lambda x: a.index(x) % 2 != 0, a)
```

EDIT: This would require for the elements to be unique and is inefficient.

Comment: This doesn't work if the list contains equal items, and even when all list elements are unique, it runs in quadratic time instead of linear.