# python - make two lists of one by writing them in the lists alternately

Tags: python, list

input: `list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
wanted output: `list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], list2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a list into two seperate lists, by every other item in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162074/splitting-a-list-into-two-seperate-lists-by-every-other-item-in-python)

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Comment: I am really new to stackoverflow. I saw: 'the question already has answers here:' so I was thinking this ended my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use slice notation with third param that is increment

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
v1, v2 = values[::2], values[1::2]
print(v1) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(v2) # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```