# How to slice a string to fetch characters at odd and even position

Tags: python, string

I have a string:

```
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

I need to print the strings with the characters present at odd and even position in the above string.

For example:

- **for odd position**, output should be:

  ```
  'ACEGIKMOQSUWY'
  ```
- **for even position**, output should be

  ```
  'BDFHJLNPRTVXZ'
  ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python program to split a list into two lists with alternating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442782/python-program-to-split-a-list-into-two-lists-with-alternating-elements)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use *string slicing*. For example:

```
>>> my_str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

# For odd
>>> my_str[::2]
'ACEGIKMOQSUWY'

# For even
>>> my_str[1::2]
'BDFHJLNPRTVXZ'
```

General syntax of *string slicing* is `string[start:end:jump]` where:

- **`start`**: is the starting index for slicing the string. Empty value means start of the string i.e. index `0`
- **`end`**: is the index till which you want to slice the string. Empty value means end of the string
- **`jump`**: is used to jump the elements from `start` such that you'll get values in the order `start`, `start+jump`, `start+2*jump`, so on till your string reaches `end`. Empty value means `1`